# Linked list won't print? C

Tags: c, function, linked-list

So my assignment is to take in letters (6 per line) of a text file, save it into linked lists, and then print out the information of specific "die"(in this case) - which is each group of 6 letters.

I've got the data to read in correctly (I think) in the `readData` function, but am unsure if that linked list is getting passed correctly. When I try to print out the linked list in `main` (lines ~40-41) I get nothing. Am I passing my function incorrectly to `readData`?

Here's my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 80

struct boggleDataNode {
    char data[3];
    struct boggleDataNode *nextData;
};

struct boggleDieSideNode{
    char dieSideData[3];
    struct boggleDieSideNode *nextSide;
};

void readData(struct boggleDataNode *temp);
void printData(struct boggleDataNode *temp);

int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    struct boggleDataNode *head;
    struct boggleDieSideNode *head1;
    struct boggleDataNode *temp;

    head = NULL;
    head1 = NULL;
    temp = head;

    printf("test\n\n");

    readData(&temp);
//    printData(temp);
    while(counter = 0, counter<100, counter++)
        printf("%s ", temp->data[counter]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void readData(struct boggleDataNode *temp) {
    //initializing variables including
    //opening the input file
    FILE *input = fopen("BoggleData.txt","r");
    char data[96] = {};
    struct boggleDataNode *new;
    int counter = 0;

    temp = new;
    //error checking that the file opened
    if (input == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    new = (struct boggleDataNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));

    while (fscanf(input, "%s", data) != EOF) {
        printf("%s ", data);
        strcpy(temp->data, data);
        printf("Data number %d %s \n",counter,temp->data);

        temp->nextData = NULL;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are iterating through the linkedlist in `main` - pretty sure there should be some sort of `while (temp->next != NULL) { temp = temp->next; }`

Comment: @M.Shaw here is where I was trying to: `while(counter = 0, counter<100, counter++)
        printf("%s ", temp->data[counter]);
`

Comment: You are just printing `temp->data[0]`, `temp->data[1]`... to `temp->data[99]` there; I don't see where you are moving to the next linked list node.

Comment: @bravesaint `temp->data` range is `0,1,2` because `char data[3];`. also type of `temp->data[counter]` is `char`

Comment: @M.Shaw crap... I just realized what you mean... I am just starting learning linked lists, completely was treating them like an array there. I assume I saved it correctly in the `readData` file function?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY this is what happens when I get frustrated and stop remembering the basics... Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `readData(temp)`. I also don't see where you are using `malloc` for every linked list node - you only `malloc` once for the head node.

Comment: @M.Shaw so I should be allocating in that while loop in the `readData` function?

Comment: @bravesaint Yes. Something like `temp->nextData = malloc(sizeof(..))` and then `temp = temp->nextData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing your structure incorrectly to `readData`. Your declare your variable like so:

```
struct boggleDataNode *temp;
```

You invoke `readData` thusly:

```
readData(&temp);
```

You declare `readData` as such:

```
void readData(struct boggleDataNode *temp){
```

So, you declare both `temp` and `readData`'s input as `struct boggleDataNode *`, but you pass `&temp` to `readData`. `&` means you are sending the address of what follows, so `&temp` is a pointer to a pointer to a `struct boggleDataNode`, which is a `struct boggleDataNode **`.

There are other problems with your code, but that is beyond the scope of your question. I will point out that your output loop is very, very wrong.

Comment: I am still very, very new to linked lists, and was taught to declare structs as `*name` as well as told to pass the struct as a pointer... I guess everything is just confusing me badly... Thank you for the response, I will try to see if I can figure out what's confusing me so much and implement thusly.